# MS ACCESS Date Validation Rule ( greater than any other data in DB)

Tags: sql, validation, date, ms-access

I'm stuck writing a MS-Access validation rule for date field in a form ([F_Bill_Date]).

This form allows me to create a billing data register and store it in a table called "Bills".

I would like to create a validation rule for the [F_Bill_Date] form field in order to ensure that the data edited in it is greater than any other data stored in the "Bills" table. Something like [F_Bill_Date] > SELECT MAX (Bill_Date) FROM Bills.

As far as I can see on tutorials, I think the rule should be something like:

> MAX ([Bill_Date]) 
>   or
>   MAX ([Bills].[Bill_Date])

but none of them works.

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid my question wasn't clear enough.I only have one table called "Bills" and a form lending me to edit the details of every new bill to insert in my unique table ( called "Bills")

Every new row I insert in this table should have a bigger value in the "Bill_Date" column than any other row already in the table.

I was looking for an  "direct" Validation Rule in ms-access to verify this functional constraint.
At the end I've decided to write a VB event function (  Private Sub Bill_Date_BeforeUpdate (.....) ).

Answer (score 1):

You can set a constraint on a table that ensures that no matter where the table is used, the constraint applies. You can trap the error using the form error event.

For example:

```
Sub AddConstraint()
'This could not be run in the query design window
'It adds a check against a table
sSQL = "ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD CONSTRAINT LimitRule " _
     & "CHECK (EventDate <= (SELECT Max(BillDate) FROM Table3))"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute sSQL
End Sub
```

See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177889(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I'm afraid my question wasn't clair eneugh.